# Что обозначает эта запись связанная с векторами?

Tags: c++, vector

`vector<int> g[1000];` и `g[i].push_back(j);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив векторов из 1000 штук, и добавление в `i`-й вектор этого массива, в конец значения `j`.

Только вот не указан тип вектора. Правильно для векторов, например, целочисленных значений -

```
vector<int> g[1000];
```

Comment: Ну вот, в вопросе исправили ошибку, и меня тут же заминусовали за то, что указал на ошибку, которой нет. По крайней мере, другого повода для минуса не вижу :)

Comment: Рекомендую завести привычку не просто читать текст вопроса, но ещё и читать исходный код через кнопку «править». Очень многие не знают Markdown и не используют синтаксис для вставки кода, и в итоге сайт съедает текст между угловыми скобками, принимая их за html-теги...

Comment: @andreymal Интересное предложение. У вас нельзя еще какой-нибудь хрустальный шар попросить - а то не все ведь не только Markdown не знают (и смотреть на экран, что получилось, тоже не умеют, так ведь? что не то видят, что набрали?), но еще и, бывает, хотят написать одно, а пишут совсем другое. Так чтоб каждый вопрос пропускать через чтение мыслей - может, автор не то хотел спросить? Хочется верить, что ваше предложение было просто неудачной попыткой пошутить...

Comment: Как достану хрустальный шар — обязательно поделюсь, а пока пользуемся тем что есть ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Напоминаю на будущее, как правильно читать такие определения.
Ищем идентификатор (имя переменной) - это g.
Идем от него вправо - там определение массива.
После прохода вправо до конца, идем от идентификатора влево.
Получается: "g это массив элементов типа vector.